# Displaying options and add to cart on category page - opencart

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart v1.5.1.3.1

I want to be able to create a template which certain categories use. Cat1 would use the normal category.tpl file where cat2 would use category-cart.tpl

The category-cart.tpl would have extra functionality of displaying price options and an add to cart button which would normally only work on the products.tpl page.

I know that in order to make this happen I have to modify the category.php controller for category.tpl file.

The question is what do I change in the category.php controller to make this happen?

Comment: Bump? >.>
I would be willing to donate a few cups of coffee to whoever can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add product with options to cart from category page http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8649

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make more changes than can be listed here, so you will need to familiarize yourself with the opencart framework to do what you want. As a starter if you look at the bottom of the category controller you will see what template is loaded. Do a search for **template**. You could put a if statement here that loads templates based on the value of the selected category.

You will then need to add more code to the controller which loads variables for price options and add to cart.

Answer (score 0):

http://opencart-help.com/modifications/39-add-product-options-to-category-listing-in-opencart.html

Check the above link and you will find out how to show the options
It should then look like this
http://i38.tinypic.com/j7b60k.jpg